# Sharex record screen audio along with microphone

Tags: screen-recorder, sharex

I have the following settings. I am able to record the screen audio but my mic audio is not being recorded.

Is there a way I can record both my mic as well as the screen audio.

[image]

Comment: Hey krv, have you checked the solution proposed by the @Angel O. Flores Torres? Because I have tested it personally and it works successfully. So Kindly check and mark it correct if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 31):

On the *"Additional command line arguments"* text field add this:

```
-f dshow -i audio="Headset (HD 450BT Hands-Free AG Audio)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest
```

In my case, where my headset (HD 450BT Hands-Free AG Audio) is also my microphone, you can find the correct name by momentarily changing the *"Audio source"* field and selecting your microphone or headset. When you select it, you will see that the *"Command line preview"* changes and the parameter `-i audio` reflects that headset name, copy that name from there and replace the quoted name in the command above.

At the end it should look like this:

[image]

(don't forget to change the audio source back to *"virtual-audio-capturer"* before pasting the additional command line arguments)

Note: the button *"Install recorder devices"* adds *"screen-capture-recorder"* and *"virtual-audio-capturer"* to the *"Video Source"* and *"Audio source"* fields respectively, in case you can't see them as available options.

Comment: Awesome this works and to this day there are people asking for this feature on GitHub. No idea what the commandline arguments mean though.

Comment: @Angel The screen recording crashes when the external micro is not plugged in. Do you know how to tell it to use it, when it's available and when not it should use the "virtual-audio-capturer"? (I asked this question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1756606 )

Comment: This is great thank you so much!

Comment: What if you have 2 different headsets? Can you add two devices to the `-i audio="xxx"`? (repeating the `-i audio=` part?

Comment: Can someone tell me where this option is in the more recent versions of the software? This is 2 years old.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem as you and I could not solve it with ShareX.

However, with [OBS](https://obsproject.com) it was straightforward to record desktop audio and microphone audio at the same time.

- Install OBS.
- Edit its graphic settings [as explained here](https://www.maxdalton.how/tutorial/how-to-fix-obs-display-capture-black-screen) - this will prevent the black screen problem.
- Open OBS.
- In the bottom-left corner, choose the "Scene".
- On the pane to its right, add three sources: "Display Capture", "Display Audio", and "Audio Input Capture".
- On the bottom right, click "Start Recording".
- Once the recording is done, click "Stop Recording".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In additional command line arguments:

```bash
-f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Yeti Stereo Microphone)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest
```

Replace Microphone (Yeti stereo Microphone) with name of device

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.