# Windows 7 - How to record Google Meeting audio?

Tags: windows-7, audio, recording, google-meet

I'm having psychoterapy through Google Meet and would like to record the sessions for studying them later. But Google does not allows recording natively except if you are the inviter and pay for a premium account. This is not the case.

How can, then, I record both the microphone and the speaker audio of my PC on the same file, without needing to downgrade the audio quality by using a second microphone to record the speakers, like I'm doing by placing a cellphone on the room and recording through it?

Comment: @harrymc The inviter is not paying Google for an account that allows him to record for me.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm asking how to use my PC to do better what I'm already doing with my cellphone. Can you point out which clause of the TOS that doesn't allows me to do what I want?

Comment: Use obsproject.com

Comment: @Gantendo: Does not support Windows 7.

Comment: @harrymc https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/whats-the-last-version-of-obs-supporting-windows-7.135449/

Comment: @Gantendo: The website says "Supports Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and Windows 11".

Comment: @harrymc Yeah those are *officially* supported. The devs tested the software using those operating systems. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmkdf19vWik & https://youtu.be/IN-vOHWhAOg?t=84 The initial release was in 2012.

Comment: Hmm, if all answers are software recommendations, then why is this question on topic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to record your desktop session with the same quality
as that of your screen and speaker, you could use a screen-recording
program.

One of the better-known is the open-source
[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/),
which can record in video the whole screen or a part of it.

There exist other products that do the same, but ShareX was the only
one among those that I checked that supports Windows 7 according to
its documentation.

Comment: Note: It's polite to let the other person know that you're recording the session, and ask his permission.

Comment: Can I record not only my speakers' audio with ShareX, but also my microphone, on the same resulting file?

Comment: If you have a microphone, it will show up in audio sources, and it will allow you to record from it. See [How to record screen with voice using Sharex ?](https://sublimelms.com/docs/Video-App-Guide/Video%20App/How_to_record_screen_with_voice_using_Sharex_.html).

Comment: From what I see, I can record OR my microphone, OR my speakers, but not both of them at the same time. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: See [Sharex record screen audio along with microphone](https://superuser.com/questions/1566658/sharex-record-screen-audio-along-with-microphone).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try EaseText. It claims to be able to record & transcribe both the microphone and the speaker audio of computer on the single file.

Comment: Hello, please provide more info for this answer and why this is the solution. "claims" sounds as if you didn't even use the software.