# ShareX: record screen audio along with microphone ONLY when it's plugged ELSE use the "virtual-audio-capturer"

Tags: audio, microphone, screen-recorder, sharex

Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1629771/235752) I added on the "Additional command line arguments" text field this:

```
-f dshow -i audio="Headset (HD 450BT Hands-Free AG Audio)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest
```

It works great when the external MIC is plugged in. But when it's not plugged in, the screen recording crashes.

How to tell it to use it only when the external micro is available (so when not it's out, it uses the "virtual-audio-capturer"?).

Comment: This is not a question, and you should probably have added the question first, and answered it yourself a day later, if no other answers provided.

Comment: the question is "How to tell it to use it only when the external micro is available (so when not it's out, it uses the "virtual-audio-capturer"?)."